How to deploy the same local lambda code, conditionally, to two different AWS lambdas using AWS SAM
I am using AWS SAM to build and deploy a lambda. I want to be able to build and deploy this code to two different lambdas, one for testing and one for prod. I am assuming there is a way to do this in the yaml file, but have not had any success.
I have tried using conditions in yaml but they seem to be ignored. I have also attempted to use two yaml files and just tried selecting different templates when building and deploying but then it just deletes the other lambda I have in there each time.

To be clear, do you want to have two different Functions in the same account, but use the same code for each of them? Or a different Function name depending on the environment?
